# ASP.NET MVC 4 avoid generation of data-val-date for datetime

Tags: validation, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4

how can I avoid the generation of the html attribute "data-val-date" for the element created from a Datetime property?

The model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
```

In fact, I'm creating a three drop down lists element for selecting the date of birth, which don't give a value in a date format.
Some solutions I've seen, consisted in a work around: removing the validation with a javascript.
The solution I envisage is to split the DateTime property into three long one for each value (day, month, year).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data-val-date is used by the validation system to validate the date.  If you remove it, client-side validation won't work.

If that's what you want, then just disable client-side validation.

Comment: Okay thanks for your quick answer. Disabling the client-side validation will have effect on every elements?
In my side, I opt for a new object containing my three values and replacing the datetime.

Comment: @bado - i'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have to precise, I just begin in web technos. I meant if I disable client-side validation, all the data-val (of all elements on the form) will have no effect?

Comment: @bado - if you turn off client-side validation then it will no longer generate any of the data-val attributes.

Answer (score 16):

Ok, this took me an afternoon of work... apparently mvc4 decided that it was time to render a data-val-date="Message" on EVERY datetime property on the viewmodel. I've tried to modify this default behaviour but didn't succeed.

This solved my problems:

```
$.validator.addMethod('date',
    function (value, element) {
        return true; // since MVC4 data-val-date is put on EVERY vm date property. Default implementation does not allow for multiple cultures...
    });
```

You can also try to write your own editor template named "DateTime.cshtml" in your shared EditorFor folder, but don't use TextBoxFor there, because that one is polluted as well.

Comment: I prefer this solution because it only disables the cause of the problem. Client side validation provides a better user experience and reduces post-backs to your server, so disabling the whole thing should be avoided.

Comment: still useful +1ed

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application start in your global.asax file and the form should fire.

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```